# Cannot make a method for ArrayList to work

Tags: arraylist, methods, bluej

I'm new to Java, and currently working in Bluej. I have a bit of a problem I can't solve and would appreciate someone helping me out.

Thank you all in advance!

I have these two classes. Song and AudioCD. And I need to write down this method in AudioCD:

" I need to write down a method that will add a new song to the disc if the length of the disc after adding this song is below the maximum length stored in maxLength. '

```
public class Song{
//Fields
private String name;
private int length; // in minutes

//Constructor   
public Song (String name, int length)
{this.name=name;
this.length=length;}

//Return methods
public String GiveName()
{return name;}
public int GiveLength()
{return length;}}
```

And other one is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class AudioCD
{//Fields
private String name;
private String singer;
private int length;
private int maxLength;
private ArrayList<Song> songs;

//Constructor
public AudioCD(String name, String singer, int maxLength)
{this.name=name;
this.length=length;
this.maxLength=maxLength;
length=0;
songs=new ArrayList<Song>();}

 }
```

I tried these two methods:

```
 public void addSong(String Name, int songlength)
 {if ((length+songlength)<maxLength) {songs.add(Name);}}
```

But this just get me a message:

1. No suitable method found for add(java.lang.String);
2. Method java.util.Collection.add(Song) is not applicable;
3. (argument mismatch;java.lang.String cannot be converted to Song);

Other one I tried:

```
public void addSong(Song Name, int songlength)
{if ((length+songlength)<maxLength) {songs.add(Name);}}
```

When I compile it, its okay. But I cannot type any parameter for Song when creating a new object.

Please help. :|

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what it is you're trying to do, but if you change the ArrayList to type `<String>` instead of the `Song` object, you can just append the song's name property (because it is a String) via `songs.add(songObject.name)`

I'm assuming you just want the ArrayList to contain the `names` of the songs